# Como retornar el valor de un HttpPostedFileBase en un metodo Post del Controlador MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Yo tengo un modelo como el siguiente:

```
public class Model_ejemplo
{
   public HttpPostedFileBase image { get; set; }
}
```

en mi controller yo recibo mi modelo con esta propiedad

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult index(Model_ejemplo Model)
{
   Return view(Model);
}
```

en mi vista este es el formulario donde capturo mi archivo

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formulario", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.image, new {type= "file", @id = "image", accept ="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"})
}
```

El problema es que siempre que retorno el modelo en la accion post del controlador este llega como Null a mi vista, y necesito devolver este tipo de datos luego de que este no halla pasado las validaciones de mi accion.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo esta aproximación, crea tu vista de la siguiente forma

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

Luego define tu acción en el controlador así (te defino un ejemplo)

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
{  
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)  
        try 
        {  
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"),  
                                       Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));  
            file.SaveAs(path);  
            ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();  
        }  
    else 
    {  
        ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";  
    }  
    return View();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba a decorar la propiedad image con [DataType(DataType.Upload)].
Es decir:

```
    public class Model_ejemplo
{
   [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
   public HttpPostedFileBase image { get; set; }
}
```